# Call a function when Xamarin.Android app closes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to call function from `MainActivity.cs` in my Xamarin.Android project.
I need to call my function after my app will be closed, not when app window will be hidden. When I tried do it using `OnStop()` void in `MainActivity.cs` it called my function only when app is actually working, but window is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call my function after my app will be closed, not when app window will be hidden.

Use [`OnDestory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#ondestroy):

> `OnDestroy` is the final method that is called on an Activity instance
> before it's destroyed and completely removed from memory. In extreme
> situations Android may kill the application process that is hosting
> the Activity, which will result in `OnDestroy` not being invoked. Most
> Activities will not implement this method because most clean up and
> shut down has been done in the `OnPause` and `OnStop` methods. The
> `OnDestroy` method is typically overridden to clean up long running
> tasks that might leak resources. An example of this might be
> background threads that were started in `OnCreate`.
>
> There will be no lifecycle methods called after the Activity has been
> destroyed.

**Update:**

Instead of `OnDestory()`, Foreground Sevice can be used when app is closed.

Comment: OnDestroy(); doesn't call my function. Probably i can enable foreground service when closing the app?

Comment: Yes, I also note that `OnDestroy()` is not called when app is closed.

Comment: You can refer to these cases: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553724/xamarin-android-run-a-method-task-even-my-app-is-close) | [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73829758/how-to-create-an-android-foreground-service-in-maui/73849475#73849475)